# Recovering of typed signature fails because it's too long

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethereumjs, signature, ecrecover

I have a typed signature generated by EIP712 V3. It is 132 characters long. I'm trying to recover it using [`recoverTypedSignature` from eth-sig-util](https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-sig-util#recovertypedsignature-data-sig). This fails saying:

```
index.js:1 Error: Invalid signature length
```

because it relies on `ethereumjs-util`'s `fromRpcSig`:

```js
fromRpcSig = function (sig) {
  sig = exports.toBuffer(sig);

  // NOTE: with potential introduction of chainId this might need to be updated
  if (sig.length !== 65) {
    throw new Error('Invalid signature length');
  }
```

How can I recover the signature? Do I need to convert the 132 characters to 65 somehow?

Comment: It should be 130-character long (hexadecimal characters, which represent 65 bytes (which will be generated when you pass the 130-character string to `toBuffer`)). You probably have an extra "0x" or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the answer was that I called the API incorrectly ‍♂️

```
recoverTypedSignature({ data: createPayload(message), sig: signature })
```

is correct. I accidentally called it with `sign` (note the extra "n").

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to convert the 132 characters to 65 somehow?

No, the line `sig = exports.toBuffer(sig)` in function `fromRpcSig` does this for you.

However, in order for it to return a buffer of 65 bytes, `toBuffer` needs to receive an input string of 130 hexadecimal characters, because each character (0-9; A-F) represents 1/2 byte (4 bits).

So your 132-character string is a wrong input here.

Now, it is possible (I can't say for sure without checking this in depth) that `toBuffer` knows how to handle the `"0x"` prefix that your input string possibly starts with.

So to begin with, what you need to do is:

1. Make sure that your string indeed starts with `"0x"`
2. Make sure that the remaining character are all hexadecimal (0-9; A-F)